# ASP.NET Identity to a remote database using RESTful API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-identity

I'm in a situation where I do not have the option to connect directly to a database (*the typical `ConnectionString` and DBContext way*), but instead, I'm forced to use a RESTful API to get and post data from, and to the database.

I difficult to explain, so here's a tiny architectural graph instead.

[image]

Easy to see, the web application can talk with the REST API, but it **CANNOT** connect directly to the database

**PROBLEM**
I'd love to use the built-in authentication system that ASP.NET Identity provides, but I'm going in completely blind. I have not been able to find any examples with REST API calls to get users, roles, etc.

I hope that some of you might be able to lend a hand. The architecture is as it is, and it's out of my hands to change it.

Comment: My team is currently using a similar system.  Our solution was to use Authentication Forms, which we found easy to setup using this article https://blog.falafel.com/dead-simple-aspnet-mvc-authentication/ .

Granted it is a bit outdated, but it works for what we wanted to accomplish with a small amount of time.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. I'm gonna give it a go. Thank you. Please write this comment as an answer so I can "upvote" it

Answer (score 1):

My team is currently using a similar system. Our solution was to use Authentication Forms, which we found easy to setup using [this article](http://blog.falafel.com/dead-simple-aspnet-mvc-authentication). Granted it is a bit outdated, but it works for what we wanted to accomplish with a small amount of time.

Sorry, I know Its not much, but it was a very easy tutorial to follow.  Feel free to ask for any more examples as you work through it!